# My Fortran program cannot open the .ini setting file under the same directory and told no such file

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

My program is written by f90 and I use the compiler fortran, the operating system is MacOS.

When I run the program, I had the following error:

```
At line 44 of file calc_configuration.f90 (unit = 10)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'control.ini': No such file or 
directory
Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10d092579
#1  0x10d093235
#2  0x10d093999
#3  0x10d1577da
#4  0x10d157a1d
#5  0x10d040868
#6  0x10d035c17
#7  0x10d078913
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files.
```

And the 44th line of calc_configuration.f90 is:

```
open(ifnTMP, file='control.ini', status='old')
```

The file control.ini is a parameter setting file like this:

```
# control.ini
# calc_start : initial date for the first one-week calculation
2004 7 21 0 0 0
..
```

I put the file control.ini under the same directory of my program, but it told me no such file.  I am confused, can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't know Mac very well, but it's possible that it's searching a default set of paths first or something odd like that.  Try writing *out* a dummy file and seeing where it ends up in the directory structure.

Comment: It works normally on a windows machine with a local file. Could you try passing the whole path of the file and see if it works?

Comment: Could you show the exact command you used to start the program, and a listing of the directory which you were in when you issued that command, please. Better still would be a short, complete program and associated set of commands and listings illustrating the problem.

Comment: I second Ian Bush's comment. Ideally, open a terminal, go to the working directory of the code, and issue the command `ls -l`, then run the program. Copy-paste all of the terminal starting at the `ls` line.

Comment: Try ./control.ini

Comment: I deleted the old control.ini. Then I tried to change the 44th line to status='new' and the program generated a new control.ini. I replaced this file with the old control file. After this my program run normally. I don't know what happened. Anyway, it is a solver